# Input integers(no limit) and finding the smallest(in C)

Tags: c, input, integer

im a beginner in C programming and im wondering how I could do this.I want to be able to input integers(as many as I want) and then finding the smallest one of them.How should I/can do this? Do I need to use an array to store them? Im not quite sure on how to do this.

Thank you!

Comment: I dont know how to start.Obviously a scanf but after this how do I make it possible any amount of numbers

Answer (score 0):

As each number is read, check to see if it's the smallest you've seen so far.  If so, set that as the smallest, then read the next number.  Repeat.

No need to store all the numbers.  Just the smallest one.

Comment: How do I check if the number that I enter is smaller than the previous one if I dont store them?

Comment: You don't need to check a number against the previous one, just the smallest you've seen so far.  You only need to store two: the current and the smallest.

Answer (score 0):

No you just have two take two variables:

```
int value=MAX_INT,value2
```

Compose a min function that returns min of two.
Then just do

```
value=min(value,value2);
```

and keep on input to value2 till EOF.